# Request.user as initial data don't work in django forms

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Porumbei, a form named AdaugaPorumbel and I want as initial data to be request.user.

```
#My model
class Porumbei(models.Model):
    COMPARTIMENTE = [
        ('Matcă', 'Matcă'),
        ('Tineret', 'Tineret'),
        ('Zburători', 'Zburători'),
        ('Decedați', 'Decedați')
    ]
    SEXE = [
        ('Mascul', 'Mascul'),
        ('Femelă', 'Femelă'),
        ('Pui', 'Pui')
    ]
    id_porumbel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    data_adaugare = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
    crescator = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    serie_inel = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, help_text="Seria de pe inel. Ex: RO 123456")

#My form
class AdaugaPorumbel(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Porumbei
        fields = ['data_adaugare', 'serie_inel', 'anul', 'culoare', 'culoare_ochi', 'sex', 'ecloziune',
              'rasa', 'linie', 'nume', 'tata',
              'mama', 'compartiment', 'status', 'data', 'vaccinat', 'info', 'imagine', 'imagine_ochi']
        widgets = {
            'ecloziune': forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y',
                                     attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'data': forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y',
                                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
            'vaccinat': forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y',
                                    attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),

            'info': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control mt-15', 'rows': '3', 'placeholder': 'Vor apărea în pedigree'}),

    }
        error_messages = {
            'serie_inel': {
                'required': 'Introduceţi seria inelului!',
                'unique': 'Porumbelul este deja adăugat în baza de date!',
            },
        }


#My view
@login_required(login_url='/auth/login/')
def porumbelnou(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdaugaPorumbel(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.crescator = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/porumbei/vizualizare')
    else:
        form = AdaugaPorumbel()
    context = {
        'form': form,
}
    template = loader.get_template("adaugare-porumbel.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

With these configuration, the crescator field is empty when save records. All I want is to assign a user to a created object. Crescator field is a foreignkey and how can i set initial data to it? Is there another way to do this? If it matters, I have a custom user model that extends AbstractBaseUser. Is a problem with this?Thanks

Comment: You seem to be doing everything correctly, `obj.crescator = request.user` should assign the user to the fk field. And you don't include `crescator` in the form so it's not part of the fields of the form, correct? (when you say "set initial data to it", that's confusing, "initial data" means populating the fields of the form **before** it is bound to data).

Comment: how are you checking that the `crescator` field is empty?

Comment: Now works. I set in my form: fields = '__all__' and it works. Thanks